# Nginx Reverse Proxy to TCP

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an `rtmp` server (no changes can be made) but I want to serve it from the main domain. How can I do this with `nginx` or similar?

```
url: rtmp: //domain.com/live/stream_id
```

I want to serve as follows.

```
rtmp: //domain.com/stream_id
```

Comment: Could you add the content of the Nginx configuration for the RTMP server?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
`stream {
    upstream backend {
 server 10.1.1.9:1935;
    }
    
    server {
        listen        1935;
        proxy_pass    backend;
    }
}`